# How to resolve WSO2 IS 5.8.0 SAML Authentication failed for signature validation

Tags: wso2, saml-2.0, opensaml, multi-factor-authentication, wso2-identity-server

Getting issue for `Signature verficiation failed` in `WSO2-IS-5.8.0`.

I'm trying the simple Email OTP Authentication tutorial given by WSO2 on the [link](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS580/Configuring+Email+OTP). I've completed all the steps but while logging to the link: `http://localhost:8080/travelocity.com` I'm getting following exception on Tomcat.

```
[org.apache.xml.security.signature.XMLSignature] : Signature verification failed.
[org.opensaml.xml.signature.SignatureValidator] : Signature did not validate against the credential's key
[org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.agent.saml.SAML2SSOManager] : Validation exception :  Ignored FQCN: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLocationAwareLog
org.opensaml.xml.validation.ValidationException: Signature did not validate against the credential's key
        at org.opensaml.xml.signature.SignatureValidator.validate(SignatureValidator.java:79)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.agent.saml.SAML2SSOManager.validateSignature(SAML2SSOManager.java:1041)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.agent.saml.SAML2SSOManager.validateSignature(SAML2SSOManager.java:897)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.agent.saml.SAML2SSOManager.processSSOResponse(SAML2SSOManager.java:581)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.agent.saml.SAML2SSOManager.processSSOResponse(SAML2SSOManager.java:525)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.agent.saml.SAML2SSOManager.processResponse(SAML2SSOManager.java:358)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.agent.SAML2SSOAgentFilter.doFilter(SAML2SSOAgentFilter.java:98)
        at org.wso2.sample.is.sso.agent.SSOAgentSampleFilter.doFilter(SSOAgentSampleFilter.java:103)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:444)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:104)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:1025)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1137)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2579)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2568)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

For the **Identity Provider** I've selected `Upload IDP certificate` for `Choose IDP certificate type`. The certificate I'm using for the same is located at `<IS_HOME>repository\resources\security\wso2.crt`. `tokenstore` directory inside the same is empty.

For **Service Provider** I've selected the option `Upload SP certificate` from `Select SP Certificate Type`. The pem I'm uploading inside it is generated with following commands from the directory: `samples\sso\sso-agent-sample\src\main\resources`

1. First Command: `'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\bin\keytool.exe' -export -alias wso2carbon -file wso2.crt -keystore wso2carbon.jks -storepass wso2carbon`
2. Second command:  `'C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\bin\openssl.exe' x509 -inform der -in .\wso2carbon.crt -out wso2carbon.pem`

I've also tried with the option of selecting `Use SP JWKS endpoint` in `Select SP Certificate Type` in `Service Provider` & in `Identity Provider` selected `Use IDP JWKS endpoint` in `Choose IDP certificate type:` still getting the same issue.

What will be the possible solution for this ? What case I'm missing out here ?
Most probably what I understand in `.pem` in SP & `.crt` in IP are not matching. How could I solve this problem.
If I've missed proper crt/pem execution, it will be great if you can add exact commands to be exceuted for certificate.